# Codeblock cannot bulid any source code which include unistd.h header file

Tags: c

I tried to build below C source code.But it fails..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 3
int add_vector(int v[]);
void error_exit(char *s);
int fork(void);
int pipe(int pd[2]);
int read(int fd,void *buf,unsigned len);
int write(int fd,void *buf,unsigned len);
int main()
{
int a[N][N]={{1,1,1},{2,2,2},{3,3,3}},i,row_sum,sum=0,pd[2];
if(pipe(pd)==-1)
    error_exit("pipe() failed");
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
if(fork()==0){
    row_sum=add_vector(a[i]);
    if(write(pd[1],&row_sum,sizeof(int))==-1)
        error_exit("write() failed");
    return;
}
    for(i=0;i<N;++i)
    {
        if(read(pd[0],&row_sum,sizeof(int))==-1)
            error_exit("read() failed");
        sum+=row_sum;
    }
    printf("Sum of the array=%d\n",sum);
    return 0;
}

int add_vector(int v[])
{
    int i,vector_sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        vector_sum+=v[i];
    return vector_sum;
}
void error_exit(char *s)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"\nERROR:%s-bye!\n",s);
    exit(1);
}








-------------- Build: Debug in pipe (compiler: Cygwin GCC Compiler)---------------

i686-pc-cygwin-gcc.exe -Wall -m32 -mwin32 -IC:\cygwin64 -c C:\Users\sangheon\codeblock_test\pipe\main.c -o obj\Debug\main.o
i686-pc-cygwin-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\pipe.exe obj\Debug\main.o  -m32  
C:\Users\sangheon\codeblock_test\pipe\main.c:13:5: error: conflicting types for 'write'
 int write(int fd,void *buf,unsigned len);
     ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/i686-pc-cygwin/sys-root/usr/include/unistd.h:4:0,
                 from C:\Users\sangheon\codeblock_test\pipe\main.c:3:
/usr/i686-pc-cygwin/sys-root/usr/include/sys/unistd.h:245:25: note: previous declaration of 'write' was here
 _READ_WRITE_RETURN_TYPE write (int __fd, const void *__buf, size_t __nbyte);
                         ^~~~~
C:\Users\sangheon\codeblock_test\pipe\main.c: In function 'main':
C:\Users\sangheon\codeblock_test\pipe\main.c:24:5: warning: 'return' with no value, in function returning non-void
     return;
     ^~~~~~
C:\Users\sangheon\codeblock_test\pipe\main.c:14:5: note: declared here
 int main()
     ^~~~
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
1 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

It says that error: conflicting types for 'write'
 int write(int fd,void *buf,unsigned len);
I always use windows version of codeblock and I know that This source code is exclusive for UNIX. So I installed cygwin compiler and select it as codeblocks' compiler.
But it fails to build this source code...
Is there any soultion to build UNIX source in windows version of CodeBlocks?

Comment: `int write(int fd,void *buf,unsigned len);` is just wrong. Remove it. Same for `fork` `pipe` and `read`. The identifiers are declared in headers - no need for you to declare them.

Comment: Why do you declare prototypes for standard functions such as `write`, `fork`, etc.? They are already declared via `<unistd.h>`

Comment: Thank you very much for reply.I quote this source code from "A Book on C: Programming in C". I finally noticed that It is needless to include <unistd.h> because fork,pipe and write function already declared at the front of source code..

Comment: It will be correct the other way: remove *your declarations*! Including `<unistd.h>` is the right way.